# MIcroServices Design when multiple microservices share the same data base

Tags: microservices

I was asked a question in inteview and i reseacrhed a lot but did not get clear answer..just wanted to know best practices so please help-

If there 10 microservices and in an ideal situation it should have their own database.but tweak here is supposed if 10 are interacting with common database how will you make it consistent.

My thought is ideally the the best choice is the database like oracle sql which follows the acid property and ensure that write is being done and the acid property is maintained but he was not happy with an answer ...ideally if one database is there then only one can write at a time and there are chances while one is writing the data another service may read the stale data so he does not wants a stale data.

i suggested having cache so that we first write in the cache then we will write in db so that another service may read from the cache and get the updated value,

he was not satisfied with that...Please share your thought. I have gone through multiple blog but did not get any satisfactory answers.

Comment: What `consistent` means in the given context? There is ACID consistency and also logical consistency(on the business layer). Are you familiar with the term `eventual consistency`?

Comment: for eventually consistent u need to have a replica and. he want updated result not eventually consistent.

Comment: _for eventually consistent u need to have a replica_: not really, though you are right, but it can be presented even with single instance of db, taking into account that there are queues involved and services communicated utilizing them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to let you know that, there is no strict rule stating that you need separate databases for different microservice.
Instead, the rule is that `Services must be loosely coupled so that they can be developed, deployed and scaled independently`.
So the pattern can be either `Database per service or Shared Database.`

In your case, it's a Shared Database pattern. Normally, people won't prefer it because they are thinking in a way like their service is directly going to access the data(in this case it will be a table) of other services. This is not correct because if your service is dependent on other service's data or database schema then your service is not going to be a loosely coupled service and not going to scale independently.

```
In the microservices world, each microservice’s persistent data is private to that service and accessible only via its API.
```

And coming back to your case, I'm not sure why your interviewer is not convinced with ACID features of a database engine since you are using the same database because the same scenario can happen in Database per service design as well. Say two threads of the same application, one is writing and the other is reading can end up in the same situation.
I think he might be expecting a different answer like the distributed transaction and SAGA patterns etc, which are not relevant in this case.